# GetDataRow method of ASPxGridView returning nothing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a DevExpress' ASPxGridView in my page with some data.

I want to get the values of a row based on an index.

Here's what I'm doing in the `RowUpdating` event:

```
Dim index As Integer = grdxFornecedor.FindVisibleIndexByKeyValue(e.Keys("IdFornecedor"))
Dim row As System.Data.DataRow = grdxFornecedor.GetDataRow(index)
```

The second line is returning `Nothing`, even with the index existing in the grid.

Anyone?

Thank you.

Comment: If you need to fetch values of row you are editing use [e.NewValues](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebDataASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs_NewValuestopic).

Comment: Actually I already solved it using another option, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ASPxGridView.GetRow](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_GetRowtopic) method instead and convert the retrieved data item to the required destination type:

```
'Dim row As System.Data.DataRow = grdxFornecedor.GetDataRow(index)
Dim row As Object = grdxFornecedor.GetRow(index)
```